# Bootstrap navbar not appearing for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby on rails application. in the meetings.scss, i have already done

```
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';
```

in my  gem file i have already bundled installed the below:

```
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem "simple_calendar", "~> 2.0"
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6' 
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.5.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false
```

However, in  my index.html.erb, I tried to do

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
</nav>

<h1>Meetings</h1>
```

But nothing is happening in the nav bar[image]

In app/javascript/packs, my application.js looks like this

[image]

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
```

Any reason why?

Comment: Have you added `//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets` in `application.js`?, paste your application.js

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma i only  see app/javascript/packs/application.js. I have edited my  description above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way to install Bootstrap (or any assets for that matter) in Rails 6 is with yarn. Here are the steps to get it to work:

**1. In your terminal**

```
yarn add bootstrap query popper.js
```

**2. In config/webpack/environment.js**

```
const webpack = require(‘webpack’)
environment.plugins.append(‘Provide’, new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: ‘jquery’,
  jquery: ‘jQuery’,
  Popper: [‘popper.js’, ‘default’]
})
```

**3. app/javascript/packs/application.js**

```
require(‘bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap’)
```

**4. app/assets/stylesheets/application.css**

```
@import bootstrap/scss/bootstrap
```

**5. app/assets/stylesheets/application.css**

```
change to app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
```

Comment: This worked! but  i don think bootstrap modals can work. I tried to use the sample bootstrap modal but the modal is not popping up

Comment: Try adding a dropdown to your navbar. If that works, you can use the same techniques to  show your modal.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Rails 5**

Rename your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` to `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` then put:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Then, remove all the *= require_self and *= require_tree . statements from the sass file. Instead, use @import to import Sass files.

Require Bootstrap Javascripts in app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

**Source**: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

If you **Rails 6 with Webpack** you can follow these steps:

https://medium.com/@guilhermepejon/how-to-install-bootstrap-4-3-in-a-rails-6-app-using-webpack-9eae7a6e2832

Comment: I edited my answer because I think you are using a webpack.